# Can't connect using mongoose and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mongoose, next.js

I'm trying to connect using mongoose but I keep getting the errors below. If I try the whole thing with MongoClient everything works.

```
import connectMongo from '../../lib/connectMongo'

console.log("TRY TO CONNECT...")
connectMongo()
console.log("CONNECTED!")
```

/lib/connectMongo.ts

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const connectMongo = async () => mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI as string);

export default connectMongo;
```

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'mongodb-client-encryption' in 'J:\react-projecte\find\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib'

and

> ./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js
> Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using Node.js version above 14.
You installed dependency using **`npm install`**
connect method need to use with await as below.

```
await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
```

Comment: Thx, but didn't solve my problem

Comment: Please mention full code of connectMongo.ts
so can help you.
Also your package,json file

Comment: ConnectMongo.ts file is always there.